# Android Kotlin cannot change a text string within a function

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin

I have some really simple Kotlin code for changing a text string within a function generated from a button press, but it does not work. I have a single button and two text strings, one the button press the first text string changes but the text string within the function does not change.

I am sure the problem is with the function call and not passing the right information about the activity, but just cannot work out what is wrong.

MainActivty.kt

```
package com.example.sandpit9

import android.content.Intent
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.view.*
import org.w3c.dom.Text

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        imageButton1.setOnClickListener {v: View -> toast(v) }

        imageButton1.setOnClickListener {
            imageButton1.setImageResource(R.drawable.greenbutton)
            textView1.text = "1234"
        }
    }

    public fun toast(v: View) {
        v.textView2.text = "1234"
    }
}
```

MainActivty.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:textSize="34sp"/>
<TextView
        android:text="textvar1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:textSize="34sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="108dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.535"/>
<ImageButton
        android:layout_width="174dp"
        android:layout_height="154dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/download"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.542"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.187"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

You're overwriting the click listener.  The `OnClickListener` is a single property - not a list.

```
imageButton1.setOnClickListener {v: View -> 
  toast(v)
  imageButton1.setImageResource(R.drawable.greenbutton)
  textView1.text = "1234"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
imageButton1.setOnClickListener {v: View -> toast(v) }

imageButton1.setOnClickListener {
    imageButton1.setImageResource(R.drawable.greenbutton)
    textView1.text = "1234"
}
```

**Problem:** `ImageButton` have only one `OnClickListener` to listen the event when there is a click event on it own. You can set the listener by using `setOnClickListener`. Because in your code, you use `setOnClickListener` two times, so the second one will override the first one.

**Solution:** Change your code to

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        imageButton1.setOnClickListener {
            imageButton1.setImageResource(R.drawable.greenbutton)
            textView1.text = "1234"
            textView2.text = "1234"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Many thanks, how simple is the solution many thanks for all the help, the setOnClickListener is setup only once to trigger the function. This is the finial code that works

```
package com.example.sandpit9

import android.content.Intent
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.view.*
import org.w3c.dom.Text

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    imageButton1.setOnClickListener{v: View -> toast(v)}

    }



private fun toast(v: View) {
    imageButton1.setImageResource(R.drawable.greenbutton)
    textView1.text = "1234"
    textView2.text = "1234"



}

}
```

Answer (score -2):

remove this import

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.view.*
```

Hope this will work

Comment: @GiorgosNeokleous Removing the import will not fix the issue. But it is still worth noting that importing anything with `.*` is not suggested.

Comment: @theThapa Thanks for pointing out. I know that's not recommended. Personally I am not a big fan of kotlin synthetics. However, if that was the answer, there should be a reason explaining why.

Comment: @GiorgosNeokleous I agree with you. If removing that import is the answer, it would be good to get some explanation.